# How to test arg in varargs

Tags: java

I have a method that accepts varargs:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
```

I'm trying to set the value of a variable based upon if an argument is passed or not.  In this case, I want to know if an 8th argument has been passed and if so set the variable's value to that argument's value, otherwise use an empty string.  I cannot hard code in args[8] on the boolean true result portion because that results in a compile error when it's ran with only 7 arguments.  So I tried the following but it also errors out:

```
String titlePrefix = ((args.length!=8) ?  "" : args[args.length]);
```

What is the correct way to test if an argument has been passed in this case and use it's value only if it has been passed?  I know that the above would give me problems should this method ever exceed 8 arguments, but for now, let's just assume that it will never have more than 8.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the fact that you care about "the 8th argument" implies you're using varargs wrong. If your method needs to do different things based on 7, or 8 args, write two methods and name your method parameters.

Comment: It will always give error when there are `8` arguments. It should be `args[args.length - 1]`.

Comment: Mike, thank you.  I didn't know I could overload "main".  I had never thought of doing that before, so I learned something new.  Thank you.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you can't overload `main`. The only entry point the JVM will consider is the one with the signature `public static void main( String[] args )` which is the same as `public static void main (String... args)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

args[args.length] should be args[args.length -1]

Comment: Thank you!  That was it.  I had tried adjusting for zero base, but had mistakenly used args[args.length]-1) instead of your args[args.length -1].  Thanks for the good eye.

Answer (score 1):

```
String titlePrefix = ((args == null || args.length<8) ?  "" : args[7]);
```

And why?

First, you may need the 9th or the 10th argument in the future. Having 9 arguments means that the 8th argument is present, so you should test whether you have **at least** 8 arguments, not whether you have **exactly** 8 arguments.

Second, for the same reason, you should not be assigning the last argument, but the exact 8th argument. After all, the last argument could be the 9th or 10th or 100th.

But even if you were testing the last argument, please remember that arrays in Java (and varargs is merely a disguised array) start from index 0 to index `length-1`. The first argument is `args[0]`, the second is `args[1]` and the eighth is `args[7]`. So to test the last argument, you have to use `args[args.length-1]`.

When dealing with varargs, it's usually best to also test for null first (although when we are talking about the `main` method, it's probably not going to happen).

Comment: RealSkeptic, that is a great solution too (using <8) but would cause an error if I had less than 7 arguments.  In my case, I will always have at least 7 arguments so it's not a problem.  But it makes me wonder, How would I do this if arguments 7 and 8 were optional?

Comment: Why would it cause an error if you had less than 7 arguments? If you had less than 7 arguments it will assign "" to `titlePrefix`. Why is that an error?

Comment: args[7] will cause a compile error.  That's why I used args.length

Comment: How about testing it? It will not cause an error because the condition will be true, so the first part of the conditional expression will be selected.

Answer (score 1):

Check this. I think that's exactly what you're looking for.

```
public class Test001 {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
            String val = args.length <= i ? "" : args[i];
            System.out.println("arg[" + i + "] = [" + val + "].");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Peter, thank you but that requires looping through the args which in my case wasn't necessary.  I only had one argument that was optional that I needed to test for.  Thank you.

Comment: Oh, OK... I just gave you a more general solution.